# Prove that $\mathbb Z _p$ is compact

Tags: general-topology

How to prove that $\mathbb Z _p$ is compact?

where $\mathbb Z_ p = \{x \in \mathbb Q _p :\| x \|_p \leq 1\}$ is the set of p-adic integers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are hints in the book #A Course in the Arithmetic# of J.P Serre. $\mathbb Z_p$ inherits a topology of $\prod \mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z$ if we define the discrete topology of $\prod \mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z$. We just need to prove that $\prod \mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z$ is compact and $\mathbb Z_p$ is closed.

Comment: You can find it here from the link: people.reed.edu/~jerry/361/lectures/zpcompact.pdf

Answer (score 3):

See this question: [Why are closed balls in the $p$-adic topology compact?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78449/why-are-closed-balls-in-the-p-adic-topology-compact)

Note, that everywhere in the answer $\frac{x_k}{p^k}$ must be changed to $x_k p^k$

Comment: The note no longer applies: that error has now been corrected.